# How can I stay logged into my account?

Tags: pokemon-go

Every time I reopen my app from fully closing it, I have to relogin with my email account. Is there anyway of remaining logged in to avoid the inconvenience of having to login each and every time I open the app?

Comment: I've removed the iOS tag As I'm having same issue on Android

Comment: I assumed this was due to server issues, as in the past 20 minutes or so it kept asking me for my email account each time I relaunched. I do not know for sure if this can be stopped now that the servers are up, but I'll let you know if I find anything out.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf It has been happening to me since I downloaded it last night :|

Comment: Grr. Those Europeans, breaking our servers. In Europe. Unlike me. Totally didn't get the APK or anything.

Comment: @Studoku, it is probably because they use the metric system. :P

Comment: @Dragonrage Yeah, we're so good at the game because we don't have to convert egg distances.

Comment: This is such an irritating issue if you log in with your Google account like I've been doing. If you have 2-factor auth enabled, you need to do that _every time_. I can't get application-specific passwords to work with this app for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Captain noted, this was due to being logged out every time the servers crashed. This has now been fixed as of patch 1.0.1 for iPhone.

> Fixes in regards to logins:
>
> Players no longer have to relog in when the game closes itself after a
>   crash -[list of patches](http://www.serebii.net/pokemongo/patch.shtml)

Comment: Not correct. This is occurring at the time of this comment in Android, and is not an OS specific issue.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience, you get logged out every time there are server issues. I was able to stay logged in for several hours last night (even when fully closing the app) and was only logged out once the servers went down.

Comment: I can confirm on this. I tested it this evening, and i did not need to choose my account, even when closing and launching the app repeatedly.